# how to fix Nexus 403 forbidden issue

Tags: ubuntu, nexus

I have created debian-remote repository. it is a proxy repository to http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/

in the nexus UI under , administration / security,have added users , roles and privileges. the nexus server is behind firewall so configured the proxy server as well. 
however, when trying to use the debian-remote repo URL in the ubuntu machine in the /etc/apt/sources.list file , getting following error ..

the entry in sources.list file is : 
deb http://192.168.48.2:8081/repository/debian-remote/ xenial main restricted

and the error is :

> 403  Forbidden Ign:7
>   http://192.168.48.2:8081/repository/debian-remote xenial/main i386
>   Packages Ign:9 http://192.168.48.2:8081/repository/debian-remote
>   xenial/main all Packages Ign:10
>   http://192.168.48.2:8081/repository/debian-remote xenial/main
>   Translation-en_US Ign:11
>   http://192.168.48.2:8081/repository/debian-remote xenial/main
>   Translation-en Ign:12
>   http://192.168.48.2:8081/repository/debian-remote xenial/restricted
>   amd64 Packages Ign:13
>   http://192.168.48.2:8081/repository/debian-remote xenial/restricted
>   i386 Packages Ign:14 http://192.168.48.2:8081/repository/debian-remote
>   xenial/restricted all Packages Ign:15
>   http://192.168.48.2:8081/repository/debian-remote xenial/restricted
>   Translation-en_US Ign:16
>   http://192.168.48.2:8081/repository/debian-remote xenial/restricted
>   Translation-en Reading package lists... Done W: The repository
>   'http://192.168.48.2:8081/repository/debian-remote xenial Release'
>   does not have a Release file. N: Data from such a repository can't be
>   authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use. N: See
>   apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration
>   details. E: Failed to fetch
>   http://192.168.48.2:8081/repository/debian-remote/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages
>   403  Forbidden E: Some index files failed to download. They have been
>   ignored, or old ones used instead.

not sure, where is the issue. the doc says that , proper deploy permission has to be configured but not sure where and how ?

please suggest

Comment: please suggest. this is stuck

Comment: Is anonymous enabled on your server?